# How to assign children to parents using Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Am running Office 2013 on Windows 10 with 16 Gb memory.

Please propose an Excel formula for the following problem.

Given an item list (e.g. items A - Z) and an outline of their relationships, how to assign children to parents?

Here is the starting point:

```
ITEM    OUTLINE
A       1
B       1.1
C       1.1.1
D       1.1.2
E       1.1.2.1
F       1.2
G       1.2.1
H       1.2.1.1
I       1.2.1.1.1
J       1.3
K       1.3.1
L       1.3.2
M       1.3.3
N       1.3.3.1
O       1.3.3.1.1
P       1.3.3.1.1.1
Q       1.3.3.1.1.2
R       1.3.4
S       1.4.
T       1.4.1
U       1.4.1.1
V       1.4.1.1.1
W       1.4.1.1.1.1
X       1.4.1.1.1.1.1
Y       1.4.1.1.1.1.2
Z       1.4.2
```

In other words, how to place all children of a parent in adjacent cells on the same row as the parent.
A solution would look like the following:

```
ITEM    OUTLINE         CHILDREN
A       1               B   F   J   S
B       1.1             C   D
C       1.1.1
D       1.1.2           E
E       1.1.2.1
F       1.2             G
G       1.2.1           H
H       1.2.1.1         I
I       1.2.1.1.1
J       1.3             K   L   M   R
K       1.3.1
L       1.3.2
M       1.3.3           N
N       1.3.3.1         O
O       1.3.3.1.1       P   Q
P       1.3.3.1.1.1
Q       1.3.3.1.1.2
R       1.3.4
S       1.4.            T   Z
T       1.4.1           U
U       1.4.1.1         V
V       1.4.1.1.1       W
W       1.4.1.1.1.1     X   Y
X       1.4.1.1.1.1.1
Y       1.4.1.1.1.1.2
Z       1.4.2
```

The table says, for example, that item J has 4 children; K, L, M and R.

Several items are leaf nodes, meaning that they have no children. Examples are items C, E, I, K, etc.

Item A is the root and has no parent.

A validation test is that the sum of the children should equal the sum of the items minus 1 (item A).

Formula only please - no VB script.

Comment: I am still trying to figure out how the outline defines a relationship.

Comment: 1 is parent 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4 are children to 1..... 1.1 has two children 1.1.1 and 1.1.2.  etc.

Comment: Suggest you rework [How to find conditional cumulative sums in an excel table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36096796/how-to-find-conditional-cumulative-sums-in-an-excel-table-using-vba-macro/36169210#36169210).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$27,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(2:$26)/((NOT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(".",MID($B3:$B$27,LEN($B2)+2,999)))))*(SEARCH($B2 & ".",$B3:$B$27)=1)),COLUMN(A:A))),"")
```

[image]

The AGGREGATE() Function was introduced in Excel 2010.

Comment: TY for catching the error on row 20 (previously was 1.4.). When I fixed my own error your solution works perfectly.

Comment: I've encountered a problem when an outline has a mult-digit level (e.g. 1.4.10). I'm uncertain how to update the LEN. Should I open a new question and wait for your advice on that new question?

Comment: @JayGray see edit. It will work for 1 or 2 digit children.  If the children get to three digit it will be a problem.

Comment: Works well. No scenario when there is 3 digit children. TY again.

Comment: @JayGray just edited again, it now does not care how many digits per child.  So if you ever do get a three digit number it will work.