# How to assign the part number of a child to a parent using excel formulas?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, parent-child

I am looking for a excel formula to read the outline (outline) of sheet 1 (Engineering Release) to determine the parent to child relationship and place the parent part number (Part No.) of the parent from sheet one (Engineering Release) to a column (Parent) for the child in sheet two (BOMUploadRelease). If it is the top-level parent, I want the column (Parent) in sheet two to be blank.

Please no VB only formulas.

Below are the highlighted columns on each sheet that I am talking about.

Sheet 1 (Engineering Release) columns:

[image]

Sheet 2 (BOMUploadRelease) columns:

[image]

Sheet names/tabs:

[image]

Also, if there is no entry on the outline column on sheet 1 then the parent column on sheet 2 will be blank.

I am hoping someone can help me. I found this post that is similar but backwards to what I need, and I am dealing with 2 worksheets rather than 1. Link to similar post: [How to assign children to parents using Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36268226/how-to-assign-children-to-parents-using-excel)

I have tried to use the level column to help determine the parent and I have tried to do the opposite of the link above to make it work for me with no good results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As sheet 2 (BOMUploadRelease) doesn't have what the correct result should be, my understanding is that the parent of outline 5.1 is 5 and outline 5.2.1.1 is 5.2.1 (see column D). The solution formula is using this understanding.

Screenshot notes:

- The left side is an equivalent to sheet 1 and   right side equivalent to sheet 2.
- Yellow highlight is for validation purposes
- Green highlight is the result looking up column B
- Gray highlight is the result looking up column C

[image: Solution Screenshot]

Only 3 ranges in the formula need to be replaced to be usable in your workbook:

- `H2` with the cell of the part in sheet 2
- `$A$2:$A$7` with the range of the outline column in sheet 1
- `$B$2:$B$7` with the range of Part No. in sheet 1

```
=LET(PART_ORIG,H2,
PART,IFERROR(MID(PART_ORIG,1,FIND("-",PART_ORIG)-1),PART_ORIG),
OUTLINE,$A$2:$A$7,
PARTS,$B$2:$B$7,
PARENT,IF(NOT(ISNUMBER(FIND(".",OUTLINE))),OUTLINE,LEFT(OUTLINE,LEN(OUTLINE)-2)),
IDENTIFY_PARENT,XLOOKUP(PART,PARTS,PARENT,"error",0),
PARENT_PART,XLOOKUP(IDENTIFY_PARENT,OUTLINE,PARTS,"error",0),
TEXT(PARENT_PART,"0"))
```

Explanation of formula:

1. PART_ORIG allows reference to the cell once, making copy/pasting and updating the formula easy
2. PART keeps everything to the left of the the first dash, e.g. 123b-R -> 123b, thus allowing exact match in column B
3. OUTLINE same concept as #1
4. PARTS same concept as #1
5. PARENT changes column A to the result shown in column D by removing the last 2 characters if it has a period
6. IDENTIFY_PARENT looks for the parent outline from #5 (see column D)
7. PARENT_PART identifies the parent part
8. last line ensures the result is in text format, even if it is actually formatted as a number. E.g. cell `B3` is a number while `B4` is a text. Without this change, if the parent part is `234`, the result would align to the right.

Comment: Adam, for some reason today I can't get your code or my code to work. Can you get the parent to work in sheet 2? https://1drv.ms/x/s!Au53oWRKuRfD9kanfyQ62uW30r1V